# Entity Framework define complex object relationship

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework

I have a **User** and **Following** class defined as such:

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public User()
    {
        Followers = new HashSet<Following>();
        Following = new HashSet<Following>();
    }

    [Key]
    public string ID { get; set; }
...
...

    public virtual ICollection<Following> Followers { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Following> Following { get; set; } 
}

public class Following
{
        [Key]        
        public int ID {get;set;}

        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string follower { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string following { get; set; }           

        public virtual User UserFollower { get; set; }

        public virtual User UserFollowing { get; set; }
 }
```

The properties follower and following in **Following** are both foreign keys for the User object and represent the relationship. Then in the DBcontext class I'm overriding the OnModelCreating:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {      
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasMany<Following>(u => u.Followers)
            .WithOptional()
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.following);

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasMany<Following>(u => u.Following)
            .WithOptional()
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.follower);
}
```

This works perfectly for getting a user's followers and following:

```
User user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(ID);
List<Following> followers = user.Following.ToList();
```

My question in basic is how do I create the UserFollower & UserFollowing relationship so that each of these properties of **Following** is mapped to a User?

Ideally I'd be able to do something along the lines of:

```
User user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(ID);
List<Following> followers = user.Following.ToList();

User userFollowing = followers[0].UserFollowing;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your model a little bit

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public User()
    {
        // Don't do this. Entity Framwork will do that for you
        // Followers = new HashSet<Following>();
        // Following = new HashSet<Following>();
    }

    // Don't add this. IdentityUser has already defined it as `Id`
    // [Key]
    // public string ID { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Following> Followers { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Following> Following { get; set; } 
}

public class Following
{
    [Key]        
    public int ID {get;set;}

    // [MaxLength(100)] No need to do this as this is Foreign Key Property
    public string follower { get; set; }

    // [MaxLength(100)] No need to do this as this is Foreign Key Property
    public string following { get; set; }           

    public virtual User UserFollower { get; set; }

    public virtual User UserFollowing { get; set; }
}
```

And then user fluent APIs to define relationship

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{      
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
        .HasMany(u => u.Followers)
        .WithRequired(f => f.UserFollower)
        .HasForeignKey(c => c.following);

    modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
        .HasMany(u => u.Following)
        .WithRequired(f => f.UserFollowing)
        .HasForeignKey(c => c.follower);
}
```

This will create a bi-directional relationship. Further EntityFramework will override all virtual properties and define behavior that you are expecting.

If you haven't modified EntityFramework configuration you will be able to do this directly

```
User user = await UserManager.FindByIdAsync(ID);
List<Following> followers = user.Following.ToList();

User userFollowing = followers[0].UserFollowing;
```

Comment: You're correct. I definitely don't need the HashSet in the constructor I was using their own documentation but realized it wasn't necessary. Thanks a bunch, I like your Fluent API usage a lot better.